# How to download "cyrtimes" package for TexWorks in Windows 7?

Tags: packages, cyrillic

Before I just wrote \usepackage{name} and the package with the according name downloaded successfully.

Now that I need to download cyrtimes package, it fails. I use TexWorks editor running on Windows 7.

Could you give me any hint please?

Comment: Do you really mean _download_? Don't you  mean _install_ a new package?

Comment: Sorry, I meant to install it. I'm just used to "download" word.

Comment: By the way, I've tried using mpm.exe but the package in question isn't on the list there.